# Picturebox background image list errors

Tags: c#, list, picturebox

With the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Form1.pbName.Count; i++)
        {
            PictureBox catchcard = new PictureBox();
            catchcard.BackgroundImage = Form1.pbName[i].BackgroundImage;
            catchcard.BackgroundImageLayout = Form1.pbName[i].BackgroundImageLayout;
            catchcard.Name = Form1.pbName[i].Name;
            catchcard.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            if (!imagelist.Contains(catchcard.BackgroundImage))
            {
                images.Controls.Add(catchcard);
                imagelist.Add(catchcard.BackgroundImage);
            }
        }
```

I am unable to determine if I have already come across a certain background image before. The check comes up false even though I feed it several picturebox background images that are exactly the same.

I give it a card array called pbName, which holds all the pictureboxes representing cards in a deck, and then perform the check. In another area of the code I declare two pictureboxes with the exact same background image and feed them into pbName and then this code snippet. However, it doesn't detect that they have the same background image and is giving me grief. Is anything above incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be try to define one PictureBox for one card

Before the loop:

```
PictureBox[] catchcardArray = new PictureBox[Form1.pb.Name.Count];
```

Inside the loop:

```
catchcardArray[i] = new PictureBox;
```

Comment: I instead switched from a list to an array like you suggested, but instead of initiliazing a new picturebox for a picturebox array, I used an image array to check against the background images of the cards, and now it works; only one card per distinct image is displayed, even if multiple exist in Form1.pbName :) thanks! Not sure why that fixed it though.

Comment: I guess is because you need distinct array index to store distinct image. Some other extra information: http://iiteeeestudents.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/possible-difference-between-image-box-and-picture-box-control/